# If variable contains a set then how do I get to 2nd item

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I display Hola in the give sample below? Right now, it's returning Hello.

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="nodevariable.xslt"?> <!--todo: change this if copying to new file-->
<!--todo: change preceding line if copying to new file-->
<greetings>
  <greeting id="1">
    <can>
      <be>
        <a>
          <long itemNo="1">
            <path>Hello</path>
          </long>
          <long itemNo="2">
            <path>World</path>
          </long>
        </a>
      </be>
    </can>
  </greeting>
  <greeting id="2">
    <can>
      <be>
        <a>
          <long itemNo="1">
            <path>Hola</path>
          </long>
          <long itemNo="2">
            <path>Mundo</path>
          </long>
        </a>
      </be>
    </can>
  </greeting>
</greetings>
```

**xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="greetings">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="greeting[@id &gt; 1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="testVar" select="/greetings/greeting/can/be/a/long[@itemNo=1]" />

  <xsl:template match="greeting">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>
          <xsl:value-of select="$testVar/path"/>
        </h1>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by moving the `testVar` declaration into your template and using it relative to the current location.

As you have it, `testVar` simply evaluates to *all* of the nodes that have that path, of which there are two.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="greetings">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="greeting[@id &gt; 1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="greeting">
    <xsl:variable name="testVar" select="can/be/a/long[@itemNo=1]" />
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>
          <xsl:value-of select="$testVar/path"/>
        </h1>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Just FYI, if you want to access the second item in a nodeset, you can use `[2]` to do so: `$testVar[2]/path`, but doing so in your example would defeat the purpose of using templates.